# Best practice for identifying the sender

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created an `IBAction` which is shared by two `UITextField`. The code is really simple, and both of them correctly call it

```
    @IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
      print(sender.text!)
    }
```

I know that I could create one `IBAction` for each of them, and the problem would be solved, but I believe that would be redundant and there should be another way to do it.

What I would like to know is if there is any attribute, such as `ID` for Android, to identify which of them is calling to the method. I have read about `tag`, but I do not find it in my `xCode` so I believe that it is an old alternative

Comment: "but I do not find it in my Xcode" What do you mean by this? `tag` is _not_ obsolete.

Comment: I thought I could find it on xCode looking into identify inspector but I do not see it. Just found something like restorationIdentifier

Comment: It's in the property inspector, the one on the right of the identity inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make outlets for those `textfields` compare the `sender` with them:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if sender == textField1 {
        print("Do stuff for text field 1")
    } else {
        print("Do stuff for text field 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, compering to the IBOutlet is a solution I did not think about it. Is it the best way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best. I see the recommended way of setting the `tag`. Which require the `textField`s to store the value and pass it .

Comment: @Mario Best way _in terms of what?_

Comment: the standard way to do it

Comment: I don’t recommend tags. Suppose you add more textFields, and then remove the original one. It’s easy to get your tags mixed up. The method in this answer is safer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Create IBOutlets for both textFields.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var firstTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet private weak var secondTextField: UITextField!
```

then you can use `switch`

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        switch sender {
        case firstTextField:
            print(firstTextField.text!)
            //other actions
        case secondTextField:
            print(secondTextField.text!)
            //other actions
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

or direct comparison

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if sender == firstTextField {
        // ...
    }
    if sender == secondTextField {
        // ...
    }
}
```